# Is there a way to break down terraform(or atlantis) output to different sections?

Tags: terraform, atlantis

My team use [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) and [atlantis](https://www.runatlantis.io/) to manage the infrastructure. We have created a repo that contains all projects' infra.

When starting a new microservice, we usually do it in this way.

1. Draft the infra in terraform git repo.

   The infra contains:

   **Backend**

   - RDS
   - Memcached
   - Redis
   - EC2

   **Frontend**

   - S3 bucket to host the static website.
   - CloudFront
2. Then, create a pull request in github and let Atlantis run `atlantis apply`.
3. Then, Atlantis displays the output in the PR.
4. Then, I copy different parts of `terraform output` to the backend team and frontend team.

[image]

### Question

Does terraform output support category or section?

Or, is there an easier way to manipulate the output of atlantis and send different sections to different teams?

Comment: No, there is no categories. You have to parse the output yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add an output map per team?

```
output "frontend" {
  value = {
    API_HOST   = ""
    AWS_BUCKET = ""
    AWS_REGION = ""
  }
}

output "backend" {
  value = {
    BACKEND_HOST = ""
    # ...
  }
}
```